# PLY - Hide output file

Tags: python, parsing, configparser, ply

I am building my parser with PLY in python and when I run the parser it creates 3 files: parsetab.py, lextam.py and parse.out

How can I not create these files? Is there a parameter to do this?
like: `yacc.yacc(fileOutput=False)`

Comment: Did you read [this](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply/issues/31) thread? Could you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28950925/edit) your question and comment on that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.out` file is for debugging purposes. Pass `debug=False` to disable. To stop writing tables, pass `write_tables=False`. However, this is inefficient if you have a non-trivial grammar, because it PLY will keep regenerating tables upon each parser build (typically at instantiation of a parser, if building inside `__init__`). Read the [PLY docs](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn36) for more details.